# Array size getting limited in PHP scandir()

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, out-of-memory

I'm using a recursive function to return a list of all the image files in a particular directory. The function works fine until a specific size of the returned array is achieved (what I assume being the issue). Is there anything else I can do to solve the issue, or an alternate that can be implemented here without the code being changed much as the application is live? Here is my recursive function.

```
function scanDirectories($rootDir, $allowext, $allData=array()) {
        $dirContent = scandir($rootDir);
            foreach($dirContent as $key => $content) {
                $path = $rootDir.'/'.$content;
                $ext = substr($content, strrpos($content, '.') + 1);

                if(in_array($ext, $allowext)) {
                    if(is_file($path) && is_readable($path)) {
                        $allData[] = $path;
                    }elseif(is_dir($path) && is_readable($path)) {
                        // recursive callback to open new directory
                        $allData = scanDirectories($path, $allData);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $allData;
        }
```

For example I have a directory having 83 image files, but I am able to return list of only 28 of them. On searching over the internet, I found that this could be a result of `memory_limit` which I can increase using `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');` in my script, which makes the memory limit to *1GB* but I am not able to solve the issue.

Comment: what error php returns? will you post that

Comment: There is no error thrown when I put it in `try catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

`scandir` is returning `.` and `..` (current and upper directory) as a list of directory. and it may cause your script to run forever with infinity recursive.

Try replace the line

```
}elseif(is_dir($path) && is_readable($path)) {
```

with

```
}elseif(is_dir($path) && is_readable($path) && $content!='.' && $content!='..' ) {
```

may fix your problem.

Comment: I don't think, that does it like how you've said, as the returned array has only the needed files in the list, and there is no upper or current directory as such. But what it has returned is far less than what it should have actually returned.

Comment: Then It's should be about permission of files or `allowext` that filter them out. I dont believe that 1GB (or even 16MB) memory is not enough for scanning 83 files :/

Comment: Yes I agree that 1 GB is way too much for this, but that didn't solved the issue as well. Now regarding permission, its set to `Read` for all the pics, so that should not be the problem either.